# how can I put image from list in template

Tags: python, django

I'm studying django and i would like to show an image of a list in the template

**views.py**

```
  data = [
            {
                "titulo": "image card 1",
                "imagem": img/image2.png",
            },
            {      
                "titulo": "image card 2",
                "imagem": "img/image1.png",
            },
        ]
return render(request, 'projects/dev.html',{'data':data})
```

template = index.html

```
<div class="pb-5 container">
    <div class="row">
         
         {%for item in data%}
        <div class="card-deck col-md-6 pt-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{item.imagem}}" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        {{item.titulo}}<br>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

obs: I'm using static files

Comment: If the image is a model field, then you can grab the image URL as `obj.image.url` (for this you should have URLs set up for static media). The template part looks pretty good.

Comment: noo, the image is a list with the path of the image in the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root urls setup for static media files:

```py
urlpatterns = []
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Views:

```py
data = Card.objects.all()
return render(request, 'projects/dev.html',{ 'data': data })
```

Template:

```
<div class="pb-5 container">
    <div class="row">
         
         {%for item in data%}
        <div class="card-deck col-md-6 pt-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="/{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.item_image.url }}" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        {{item.titulo}}<br>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case I have to transform my list into an object?

Comment: Yes, for images it's better to use model objects so that we can add/delete them using the API or UI.